# How to calculate distance between two points using geosparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, stardog, geosparql

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two points using `geosparql`. I have objects like the following image (same properties, different values):

[image]

And I'm executing that query in `sparql`:

```
PREFIX geos: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geosf: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/frubi/ontologies/2017/10/puntsWIFI#>

SELECT ?distance
WHERE {
    ?wifipoint1 :hasGeometry ?geo1 .
    ?geo1 geos:asWKT ?wpoint1 .
    FILTER sameterm(?wifipoint1, <http://www.semanticweb.org/frubi/ontologies/2017/10/puntsWIFI#NYWifiFree103>) 
    ?wifipoint2 :hasGeometry ?geo2 .
    ?geo2 geos:asWKT ?wpoint2 .
    FILTER sameterm(?wifipoint2, <http://www.semanticweb.org/frubi/ontologies/2017/10/puntsWIFI#NYWifiFree105>) .
    ?distance geosf:distance(?wpoint1 ?wpoint2 <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#Kilometer>)
}
```

Without adding the distance, I'm able to get the following result:

[image]

But at the moment I add the distance I get empty rows. Any idea?

Notes:

- I need to calculate the distance between two wifipoints (NYWifiFree103 and NYWifiFree105) which have each one a point.
- I'm executing that queries in stardog.

** **EDIT** **

I simplified the query:

```
PREFIX geos: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/frubi/ontologies/2017/10/puntsWIFI#>

SELECT (geof:distance(?wpoint1, ?wpoint2, <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#Kilometer>) as ?distance)
WHERE {
    ?wifipoint1 :hasGeometry ?geo1 .
    ?geo1 geos:asWKT ?wpoint1 .
    FILTER sameterm(?wifipoint1, <http://www.semanticweb.org/frubi/ontologies/2017/10/puntsWIFI#NYWifiFree103>) .
    ?wifipoint2 :hasGeometry ?geo2 .
    ?geo2 geos:asWKT ?wpoint2 .
    FILTER sameterm(?wifipoint2, <http://www.semanticweb.org/frubi/ontologies/2017/10/puntsWIFI#NYWifiFree105>)
}
```

When I set in `geof:distance` two harcoded `wktLiteral` returns me correct distance, but using Points does not return nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't you simply use `SELECT (geosf:distance(?wpoint1 ?wpoint2 <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#Kilometer>) as ?distance) WHERE ...`?

Comment: @AKSW I tried it, but still getting emtpy distance

Comment: What means "empty"? You should at least get some number. What happens if you use it via `BIND` inside the query? Do you have the spatial index enabled?

Comment: And what is `geos:asWKT` ? The prefix `geos:` doesn't exist in your query, it must be `geo:asWKT`

Comment: Empty means that returns 0 items, without any number in distance

Comment: And sorry I fixed the `geos` prefix

Comment: How can I know if I have the spatial index enabled?

Comment: Same result by binding the query using `BIND (geof:distance(?wpoint1, ?wpoint2, <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#Kilometer>) as ?distance)`

Comment: At some point, you should have done something like `stardog-admin db create -o spatial.enabled=true -n ...`

Comment: @AKSW Yes, it is enabled then

Comment: Also I installed in server/ext folder of stardog jts library in order to use geosparql. I'm using stardog Enterprise too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geof:distance` function accepts Geometries as its first two parameters. So with your simplified query, using `geof:distance(?geo1, ?geo2, unit:Kilometer)` should give you the result you desire. The Stardog Blog has a [geospatial primer post](https://www.stardog.com/blog/geospatial-a-primer/) that you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

AKSW is correct, you should use the built in [geof:distance function](https://www.stardog.com/docs/#_sparql_integration) for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with GraphDB. instead of distance it returns 2 fields empty and I have already enabled geosparql

Here is my code:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/evangelos/ontologies/2019/2/untitled-ontology-2#>
prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
prefix geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
prefix unit: <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#>
prefix sf: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#>
prefix test24: <http://www.semanticweb.org/evangelos/ontologies/2019/2/untitled-ontology-2#>
prefix omgeo: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/geo#>

SELECT (geof:distance(?point, ?point2, <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#Kilometer>) as ?distance)
WHERE
{
    :MouseioMetaksisSoufliou :hasGPSCoordinates ?geom2.
    ?geom2 geo:asWKT ?point.
    ?geom3 geo:asWKT ?point2.
    FILTER (?geom2 != ?geom3)
}
```